# Easily add data from database to multidimensional array using php

Tags: php

How can I easily add data from MySQL to a multidimensional array in PHP? I am making a search box and I want to store the first name, and the last name in the array.

Why does not this work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['primary']] = $row['firstname'], $row['lastname'];
}
```

Comment: learn basic php. `$data[$row['primary']] = array($row['firstname'], $row['lastname']);`. And if all you wanted as the firstname/lastname, that's all you should have selected, and the lien woudl be `$data[$row['primary']] = $row`

Comment: Ahh, Thank you. Worked out very well.

Comment: You can add this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data[$row['primary']] = array($row['firstname'], $row['lastname']);
```